# How want to Create in Eclipse and run Appium test on Android device?

Tags: android

[How to create in Eclipse and run your Appium test on the iOS device (not emulator) where app is installed prior to the execution of the test script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919159/how-to-create-in-eclipse-and-run-your-appium-test-on-the-ios-device-not-emulato)

from the link above as I am trying to follow the steps. I am stuck at step 11 as I am trying to get my android device to set up with Eclipse and run Appium. I am having problem with following codes as folows

```
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "ios"); (changed "IOS" to "Android")
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","iOS"); (changed "IOS" to "Android")
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", “<<<your iOS device UDID>>>”); ( I know my IMEI number for the device)
    capabilities.setCapability("app", “<<<your app’s bundle id>>>”); (?????)
```

And then when I continue with the steps seems like it's not working as it should especially with step 15 & 16. When I copy and paste command in step 16 I get the follow messages as follows:

```
mvn -Dtest=test.java.com.saucelabs.appium.AppiumIOSTest test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: You may want to not use Eclipse anymore. Here is an Android Studio link. http://testdroid.com/tech/appium-tip-20-executing-appium-tests-with-gradle